# Payroll taxes per state in the United States

Tags: data-request, usa, finance, taxes

I am looking for a dataset containing which state payroll taxes individuals residing in the United States must pay, broken down per state.  E.g., Washington tax residents must pay a 0.58% long-term care insurance payroll tax (unless they have managed to opt out of it).

Some state payroll taxes are employer contributions (e.g., Unemployment Insurance (UI) and Employment Training Tax (ETT)  in California) while some others are withheld from employees’ wages (e.g., State Disability Insurance (SDI) and Personal Income Tax (PIT) in California). I'm only interested in state payroll taxes withheld from employees’ wages.

E.g. the dataset could be something like (the number for CA is made up):

| US State | Payroll tax rate withheld from employees’ wages. | Tax name(s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| California | 3% | State Disability Insurance (SDI) and Personal Income Tax (PIT) in California |
| Texas | 0% |  |
| Washington | 0.58% | long-term care insurance tax |
| [...] | [...] |  |

https://gusto.com/tools/employer-tax-calculator ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20211101024712/https://gusto.com/tools/employer-tax-calculator)) only contains state payroll taxes that are employer contributions, whereas I want state payroll taxes withheld from employees’ wages:

[image]